# what namespace and reference should i add for INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: silverlight-3.0

i am getting this error  message

The type or namespace name 'INotifyPropertyChanged' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

what  namespace and reference  should i add  for  INotifyPropertyChanged

any help would be  great

Answer (score 6):

INotifyPropertyChanged is in package `System.ComponentModel`

Comment: you solved one  problem.
and  for   ObservableCollection  what namespace ?

Comment: System.collection.objectmodel. As a note, if you position your cursor at the end of a class name and hit CTRL + SPACE visual studio will try to determine the namespace for you.